# Xcode misbehaviour in quick help window only or also the probable cause of 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle from

Tags: ios, xcode7, xib

I am unable to load a nib in my bundle for my tableview and it's the same way i have done before. Seems like this might have to do something with this : 
[image: Clearly my subclass is from UITableViewCell]

But if you check out the quick help window below, it shows my variable is a UITabbarController?

[image]

Why? Why?

Comment: You need call `self.tableView registerNib:`method in your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Did like so  [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];